# Finding an equivalence relation that isn't a congruence.

Tags: modular-arithmetic, equivalence-relations, semigroups

Let $B=S \times T$ be a [rectangular band](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Band_(mathematics)#Rectangular_bands) such that $|S|=|T|=3$.

I've got to find an equivalence relation which is not a congruence in order to prove that at least one exists.

I've tried many different equivalence relations, but they have all turned out to be a congruence. 
Any help on how I would find one would be great.

Thanks.

EDIT: The operation on $B$ is: $(s,t)(s',t')=(s,t')$

Congruence is defined as :  for $((s,t),(s',t')),((x,y),(x',y'))$ contained in the the equivalence relation $R$, $((s,t)(x,y),(s',t')(x',y'))$ is also contained in $R$.

Comment: On which set are you working?

Comment: What is the definition of congruence in this context?

Comment: Which operations?

Comment: The operation on B is: (s,t)(s',t')=(s,t')

Congruence is defined as :  for ((s,t),(s',t')),((x,y),(x',y')) contained in the the equivalence relation r, ((s,t)(x,y),(s',t')(x',y')) is also contained in r.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. Try to find a counterexample when $|S| = |T| = 2$, this is easier. An equivalence relation on a set defines a partition of the set. Just find a partition of $S \times T$ into two sets which does not define a congruence on $S \times T$.